# Change current location while monitoring region when App is killed

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I want to change my current location when the App is not running so that i can monitor any region using `startMonitoringForRegion` when the App is not running.

I know I can change location using Xcode but it is only possible when the App is running. Do I need to create another App which will change my current location?

Comment: You can change your location in the Simulator debug menu

Comment: This is only possible when the App is running through simulator. But I want to change when the App is not running.
So that App will have `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` in the `launchOptions`.

Comment: Yes.  You should also be able to change the phone's location while debugging another app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh thanks. :) I also want to know that what's the response when `[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"]` have some value. Can I display it in alert?
Please see this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/28831572/3855476