# startMonitoringForRegion when App close

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am using `startMonitoringForRegion` to monitor specific region.
When App is not running I have successfully generated a local notification when a user enters/leaves a particular location by comparing `[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"]` in AppDelegate.

But now I am not able to understand how can I know that a user enters in a location or leaves a location.
I am not able to find a way to check the response. Can I show the response in the alert body?
I searched in internet but unable to find any tutorial that have written some code in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use location manager delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

    if (state == CLRegionStateInside) {

        // We entered a region
         NSLog(@"Inside region");
 if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground){

            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.alertBody = @"Region Detected";
            notification.soundName = @"Default";
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];


    } else if (state == CLRegionStateOutside) {

       // We are outside region
        NSLog(@"Outside region");
    }
}
```

IN APPDELEGATE

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PerformAction" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

IN your ViewController viewDidLoad Method :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performAction) name:@"PerformAction" object:nil];
```

In your same viewController add the following method and perform ur action

```
-(void)performAction
{
  // perform your action
}
```

Comment: In AppDelegate I have to write this?
I am comparing `[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"]` in AppDelegate inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

So what I need to write your code inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ??

Comment: but why u want to write the code in appdelegate? u can determine using this delegate method if user is in the monitioringregion or not

Comment: When my App is not running and I enter the location then App relaunches itself. So I have to write some code in AppDelegate to say what to do next. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174042/ios-corelocation-and-geofencing-while-app-is-closed/17174344#17174344).

Comment: so u can create a local notification to notify the user.

Comment: Yes I am generating a local notification but then I don't know weather user enters a location or exits and what's the Region->Identifier so that I know the place and do some further tasks.

Comment: Is there any way to write the response as an alert message after local notification is generated?
Or can you please give me the response, if you have any idea?

Comment: I have to write location manager delegate method in my View Controller.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes u have to use the location manager delegate method in viewcontroller

Comment: I have done the same as you mentioned but performAction method is not called.

Can I get the UUID (Region Identifier) AppDelegate. Actually I have to know  the UUID even if your code works because on the basis of this UUID I have to done further tasks.

Comment: declare your uuid globally.. or is there going to be different uuids

Comment: I can't declare it globally. It's different for different monitoring regions.